# How to upload .dll files to github?

Tags: git, github

I have seen many github users uploading .dll files but I can't get the trick to upload them.

> Do I have to open it with notepad and then copy the content and then upload it ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve anyway? Are you trying to provide a download link or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot upload binary files through the GitHub UI. You must commit them to your repository locally and then push to GitHub via Git.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to github. Can you be more precise ?

Comment: First, be clear that Git is not GitHub. Git is a version control system in which you create a repository and commit changes one at a time. GitHub is a website that hosts your Git repository. GitHub's UI only supports creation and editing of text files, so if you need binaries, you need to use Git directly. Start with [Git - Getting Started](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started) to understand the basics.

Comment: And committing dlls is a bad practice, so should be avoided, except in some very specific cases...