# DLL files partially downloaded using Github UI

Tags: git, github, dll

I just noticed that I have many missing .dll files on my Github repository (C# .NET project). I was wondering where they have gone until I saw [this accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548862/how-to-upload-dll-files-to-github) that says:

> You cannot upload binary files through the GitHub UI. You must commit
>   them to your repository locally and then push to GitHub via Git.

I have never directly used Git and have *only* used the Github Desktop UI to commit my code. I am wondering, if you cannot upload binary files, how did the rest of them go through?

Comment: I think "GitHub UI" refers to the web interface, not to the desktop client.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several options:

1. You have `.gitignore` which ignores certain files and folders so they were not uploaded.
2. You did not add those files to the staging area so those files were not commited and as a result were not uploaded to the server as well.

To find out is there are ignored run this command:

```
git check-ignore * -v
```

This will print out the list of all your ignored files along side with the location in your `.gitignore` line.

---

Check to see if the files have not beed added to your staging area.

```
# Open terminal or git-bash and than
git status
```

If the files were not added you should see something like this:
[image]

Add the files and commit + push again and they will be uploaded

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem I now have is that I no longer have access to my old DLLs and should someone find them through the production code. So even Github Desktop App does not upload the DLL libraries? I think the reply in my message is about the Web UI.